# Create dynamic Pydantic model with typed optional values

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to create a dynamic model from my data, create JSON from it, and load it in another location.

I can't find a way to define a field in a way, that should it is optional, but when data exists for that field - it would be validated.

This is for required field:
`fields[col_name] = (data_type, None)`

```
# resolve types for data
data_type = resolve_type(data)
required = is_required(data)
if required:
  fields[col_name] = (data_type, ...)
else:
  fields[col_name] = (data_type, None) <--- unclear

...

pydantic.create_model(name, **fields)
```

The above configuration generates JSON model that makes fields optional and typed, but then I validate by using the input data I can't pass `None` values -  `'$.inputs.0.Field', 'message': "None is not of type 'string'"`

So my question - how to declare a field that would validate input, but only when it's not None.
And in such a manner, that I could create JSON schema and load it in another location.

Comment: I had the same issue as well (with predefined models). At the moment there is no support for fields that are optional, as it seems that for the author either you have all the data or none. This issue could help https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/990

Comment: Yeah, implemented workaround based on that issue.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to face similar problems with fastAPI when I want only certain fields to be updated, I have to resubmit the whole data object and verify that some old things match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented workaround based on suggestions in https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/990

```
optional_fields = list()
if required:
  fields[col_name] = (data_type, ...)
else:
  fields[col_name] = (data_type, None)
  optional_fields.append(col_name)

model = pydantic.create_model(name, **fields)

def schema_extra(schema, model):
    for column in optional_fields:
        original_type = schema["properties"][column]["type"]
        schema["properties"][column].update({"type": ["null", original_type]})

model.__config__.schema_extra = schema_extra

schema_json = model.schema_json()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Foo = create_model("Foo", foo = (int, None))

Foo(foo=None)
# Foo(foo=None)

Foo()
# Foo(foo=None)

Foo(foo=3)
# Foo(foo=3)
```

Is this your desired result?

Comment: This is not dynamic since you know that you are receiving `foo`. What if I don't know what key is coming in a json?

Comment: See Martynas Jurkus's answer,  you can use a dict define the code, and use  `**kwargs` as the arguments of `create_model`